# what is the use of manual bootstrapping in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I read in an article that the Angular JS application can be Manually Bootstrapped.What is the meaning of Manually Bootstrapping the Angular application and how is it done?

Comment: Read another article or refer [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have more control over the initialization process, you can use a manual bootstrapping method instead.
Please go through the below code.

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    Hello {{greetMe}}!
  </div>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.js"></script>

  <script>
    angular.module('myApp', [])
      .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.greetMe = 'World';
      }]);

    angular.element(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```